# Annotate words in a 3D Scatter Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to annotate words on a scatterplot.

X is the result NLP preprocessing (dataframe of integers) and words is a list of words with same lenght as X and related to it.

print(X)

```
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
result = pca.fit_transform(X)

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(result[:,0], result[:,1], result[:, 2], cmap='Greens')
for i, txt in enumerate(words):
    ax.annotate(txt, (result[:,0][i],result[:,1][i]))
```

[image: PCA on a text]

Nonetheless, as shown in the picture, text description of words does not work properly, leaving a few instances without annotation.

How can I add the corresponding word to each datapoint in the 3D plot?

Comment: [This example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/text3d_demo.html) shows how to place text in 3D plots. You are placing the text in 2D coordinates, hence most points will be outside the figure.

Comment: I think this might work better for you than the `ax.annotate` function: `ax.text(result[:,0][i],result[:,1][i],result[:,2][i], txt)`

Comment: How would you suggest to implement it in the script? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: It works! @xnx thank you so much